# How can I read the object (basically Json data) from the http,get in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am new to the Angular (so this might be silly doubt)
I am building a service where I could call the function from any component and use the service function to provide me the json value in form of object.
So i am calling the function from my component and then trying to print my value on console

This is the `app-component.ts` file

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CallServiceService } from './call-service.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  message: string;
  obj;

  constructor(private callservice: CallServiceService, private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log("Here in component");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.callservice.calledService(this.obj, '/assesment/GetHeaderDetails');
    console.log(this.obj);
  }
}
```

and my service file is `call-service.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CallServiceService {
  base_api_url: string = "http://localhost:5000/";
  process: string = "";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  calledService(end_url: string) {
    return this.http
      .get(this.base_api_url + end_url)
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(data => obj.successCallback(data));
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

So i need to read the value in component file but that is not showing the desired output

Comment: You should subscribe in the service, not in the component

Answer (score 1):

subscribe calledService in the component.

**SERVICE**

```
calledService(end_url: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.base_api_url + end_url);
    // remove subscriber
}
```

**COMPONENT**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.callservice.calledService(this.obj, '/assesment/GetHeaderDetails')
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    // Assign data to some variable and use in HTML
}
```